# comparing more than 2 columns in a csv file and create new column in the csv file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have 2 csv files( 1.csv and 2.csv). Number of columns in both the files are same.

```
1.csv

Server,Path,I/P Backlog,O/P Backlog
Server1,Yes,3000,200
Server3,Yes,8,0
Server5,Yes,0,0


2.csv

Server,Path,I/P Backlog,O/P Backlog
Server1,Yes,3300,180
Server3,Yes,7,0
Server5,Yes,0,0
Server6,Yes,10,200
```

I have to compare 3 different columns in both csv.

IN above example, if server name is same, then find the deviation percent of I/P backlog and o/p backlog and create 2 separate columns for input trend and output trend.

if value is same: Nochange.
if value has increased then it should increase % (up)
if value has decreased: decrease % (down)
if new row has been added: New
if any row doesnt exist in second report , nothing needs to be done.

So my final sheet should show as below.

```
Server  Path    I/P Backlog Input Trend O/P Backlog Output Trend
Server1 Yes 3300    10%(up) 180 20%(down)
Server3 Yes 7   20%(down)   0   No change
Server5 Yes 0   No change   0   No change
Server6 Yes 10  New 200 New
```

Comment: `180` - is `10%` decrease from `200`, not `20%`

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post

Comment: Hi Roman.. Yes it 10% decrease.. it was my mistake...

Comment: @user2642751, what if some `I/P Backlog` value in `2.csv` is `10` and the respective value in `1.csv` is `0` ? In such case - there's no way for percents

Comment: Good question.. i need to think about this... may need to ignore this scenario...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'function percent(v){ 
         if (v !~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/){ return v } 
         coef=1; dev="down"; 
         if (v >= 1){ coef=-1; dev="up" } 
         return sprintf("%d%(%s)",(100-v*100) * coef, dev) 
    }
    NR==1{ 
        $4=$4 FS "Input Trend"; 
        $6=$6 FS "Output Trend"; 
        print 
    }
    FNR==1{ next }{ k=$1 FS $2 }
    NR==FNR{ a[k]=$3 FS $4; next }
    k in a{ 
        split(a[k], vals); 
        if ($3==vals[1]) ip_diff="No change"; 
        else if (!vals[1]) ip_diff=$3"(up)"; 
        else ip_diff=$3/vals[1]; 
        if ($4==vals[2]) op_diff="No change"; 
        else if (!vals[2]) op_diff=$4"(up)"; 
        else op_diff=$4/vals[2]; 
        print k, $3, percent(ip_diff), $4, percent(op_diff); next 
    }
    { print $1,$2,$3,"New",$4,"New" }' f1.csv f2.csv
```

The output:

```
Server Path I/P Backlog Input Trend O/P Backlog Output Trend
Server1 Yes 3300 10%(up) 180 10%(down)
Server3 Yes 7 12%(down) 0 No change
Server5 Yes 0 No change 0 No change
Server6 Yes 10 New 200 New
```

Comment: Thanks Roman for your help.. however it is not showing anything apart from NEW.  Server,Path,I/P Backlog,O/P Backlog  Input Trend   Output Trend
Server1,EP,3300,180   New  New
Server3,DC,7,0   New  New
Server5,DC,0,0   New  New
Server6,EC,10,200   New  New

Comment: @user2642751, that's NOT true. Here's a screenshot https://ibb.co/iR8V2R. What's your `awk --version`?

Comment: sorry.. i am not able to find the version.. still trying to get..  tried /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -V version    /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -W version       /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -version

Comment: what /bin/awk
/bin/awk:
        SunOS 5.10 Generic 148336-01 Dec 2011

Comment: @user2642751, I meant not finding the command text but running the command `awk --version`

Comment: your help on this much appreciated.. please suggest me what could be wrong on myside...

Comment: Hi Roman, i just noticed you have considered spaces or tabs in f1.csv and f2.csv file. Actually i copied data from an excel sheet. So basically it is separated with comma(,). could you please let me know what should be our new code...                                                               
Server,Path,I/P Backlog,O/P Backlog
server1,EP,3000,200
server3,DC,8,0
server5,DC,0,0

Comment: add field separator `awk -F',' ...`

Comment: i have used same now.. my input file i have updated above..however in output %s is coming and am expecting comma separated output as well...                                                                                            Server Path I/P Backlog O/P Backlog,Input Trend  ,Output Trend
Server1,Yes 3300 10%s) 180 10%s)
Server3,Yes 7 12%s) 0 No change
Server5,Yes 0 No change 0 No change
Server6 Yes 10 New 200 New

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163240/discussion-between-user2642751-and-romanperekhrest).

Comment: @user2642751, I've posted an extended solution which should work in a very most cases on Linux systems. So. instead of digging into troubles you may try to choose some good operation system with good tools

Comment: thanks for your comments Roman.. i am using in another server where it is running fine.. only thing FS is causing problem i guess...Thats the reason i am looking for your help..Can you just try once with new csv files and execute..

Comment: There was some issue in %s and i have modified as mentioned below...          return sprintf("%d%%(%s)",(100-v*100) * coef, dev)                                        and it worked fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Roman.. Is it possible if you can write some comments about each line which you have mentioned in solution?